# Multi String search in Data frame in Multiple column with AND or OR Option

Tags: python, pandas, search

I can do a single word search in each column but unable to search user-provided number of string search with "and" "or" option

```
   0     1    3   4     
0 [OH-] [Na+] NAN CCO 
                                              
1 [OH-] [Na+] CCO  Cl
```

This one works

```
search = 'CCO' 
df.loc[df.isin([search]).any(axis=1)].index.tolist()
```

For multi-search I tried

```
import re

terms = ['C1', 'CCO']
p = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, terms)))
df[df['col'].str.contains(p)]
```

Gives me `KeyError: 'col'`

Expected output

```
Search='C1' AND '[NA+]
```

Results `1`

```
Search='CCO' OR 'C1'
```

Results `0 1`

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created your dataframe this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( { 0 : ["[OH-]","[Na+]","NAN","CCO" ], 1 :  ["[OH-]","[Na+]","CCO","Cl"] } ).transpose()
```

Yielding this df:

```
       0      1    2    3
0  [OH-]  [Na+]  NAN  CCO
1  [OH-]  [Na+]  CCO   Cl
```

I observed that you can do your OR logic with the isin() function on the df:

```
df.isin(['CCO','C1'])
```

Yields:

```
       0      1      2      3
0  False  False  False   True
1  False  False   True  False
```

And so you can figure out which rows match using `any(1)` as you are using:

```
df.isin(['CCO','C1']).any(1).index.tolist()
```

Yields:

```
[0, 1]
```

Logic for AND:

The snippet below looks for each term individually and accumulates them in the results dataframe.  After finding matching columns, the number of matches in each row is checked to see if it matches the number of terms.

```
results = pd.DataFrame()
terms = [ 'Cl', '[Na+]' ]  
for term in terms:
      if results.empty:
        results = df.isin( [ term ] ) 
      else:
        results |= df.isin( [ term ] ) 

results['count'] = results.sum(axis=1)
print( results[ results['count'] == len( terms )  ].index.tolist() )
```

I know there is a better way - but this way works (I think)

The above code yields `[1]` for `terms = [ 'Cl', '[Na+]' ]`   and `[0,1]` for `terms = [ "[OH-]","[Na+]" ]` .

Answer (score 1):

Because there isn't a column name `col`. Try this:

```
df[df.apply(lambda col: col.str.contains(p)).any(axis=1)]
```

`col` is now the name of an input parameter to the lambda.